# log4j redirection to desktop application in swing

Tags: java, swing, logging, log4j, appender

I have a GUI application in swing, implemented in NetBeans. For the various functionality provided from the input of the user, a jar is used, which uses log4j for logging. All is ok, but I have to redirect information from log4j to a text area in my GUI. I have found that to redirect from log4j to swing text area, one must extend an AppenderSkeleton. My problem is that I can not modify the gui (so as to have a JTextArea that extends an AppenderSkeleton for example) so I have to have such a class that appends to my JTextarea. Now my application initializes **before** log4j. My problem is that I can not find a way to set as property to the AppenderSkeleton custom class, a reference to the jtextarea of my gui , so that when log4j initializes the appender, it will pass a reference to the application's text area.
I tried in the log4J configuration file something like:
log4j.appender.myAppender.theTextArea=path.to.myFrameclass.theTextArea
hopping that log4j would call the setter in my appender and the getter from my frame to set the text area, but it does not work.
How can I make the appender initialized by log4j, redirect info to my application?
Or is there a way for my application to initialize the custom appender and notify log4j to use it for logging?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest option is to programmatically add your appender once your GUI has been initialised. Something like this:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(yourTextAreaAppender);
```

EDIT: To only log the INFO level do this:

```
yourTextAreaAppender.addFilter(new Filter() {
    @Override
    public int decide(LoggingEvent event) {
        if (event.getLevel().equals(Level.INFO)) {
            return ACCEPT;
        } else {
            return DENY;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I did a class myTextAppender extends AppenderSkeleton{ JTextArea area; //getters and setters of textarea}. When the gui initializes I do the myTextAppender a = new myTextAppender(); a.setArea(this.getTextArea());Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(a); but I get log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.WINDOW in the log4j. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Russ: I removed the log4J configuration file and it works. Is there a way to append only the logging messages of INFO and not WARNING?

Comment: Yes this should work: yourTextAreaAppender.setThreshold(Level.INFO);

Comment: @Russ: I tried it. I prints all messages of INFO level and higher. Is there a way to append only the INFO messages (not WARN or ERROR level as well)?

Comment: Yes use a filter - I have added it to the question to enable syntax highlighting.

Comment: If my AppenderSkeleton's append() method calls a method foo() that calls log.debug("XYZ"), my AppenderSkeleton's append() method is called with the LogEvent generated by foo() [with message=XYZ"].  My  AppenderSkeleton then calls foo() again, and the cycle repeats forever.  Can my AppenderSkeleton's decide() method be used somehow to prevent it from acting on LogEvents generated getting into this loop?

Answer (score 1):

Well this could be pretty simple,

1. Specify the property in log4j.property file, in my case it is:

   ```
   log4j.rootLogger=S
   log4j.appender.S=com.ibm.nzna.projects.qit.gui.StatusMessageAppender
   log4j.appender.S.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.S.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
   ```
2. Write is new class with the following code :

   ```
   import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
   import org.apache.log4j.Level;
   import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

   /**
    * @author Ashish Tyagi
    *
    */
   public class StatusMessageAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {
       private StatusBar statusBar = AppDefaultWin.getStatusBar();
       protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
           if(event.getLevel().equals(Level.INFO)){
                   //here set the text of your swing component;
                  //in my case it is: statusBar.st_STATUS.setText(event.getMessage().toString());
           }
       }

       public void close() {

       }
       public boolean requiresLayout() {
           return false;
       }

   }
   ```